# Obtaining $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from the Gradient Vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Note: This looks like a duplicate  but my question lies on the relation of the slope and the components of the gradient vector.

I am asked to solve for the path that raindrops will follow (steepest descent due to gravity) in an ellipsoidal dome $z = \frac{√{(16-4x^2-y^2)}}{4}$

Then $−∇f(x, y) = \frac{(4 − x^2 − \frac{y^2}{
4})^{−1/2}}{2}
(2x, y/2)$

Now, the book stated that I need to solve the solution to the ordinary differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{y}{2}}{2x}$

My question is, why is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ obtained by dividing the $\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}$ component of the $−∇f(x, y)$ with its $\boldsymbol{\hat{i}}$ ?
When there is a formulation like $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}}$ which gives a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-\nabla f(x,y) = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat{i} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \hat{j}$$

this gives me
$$
\dfrac{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} }{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} } = \dfrac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} }{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} }
$$
i.e. no minus sign.

Comment: My mistake, I have a typo in the component part. The problem is the book used $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} }{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}}$ instead of the formula above